# Are flowers profitable in any way?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

Are flowers intended to be the main staypieces of your town and not intended for selling? The reason I ask is because from the flowers I've picked off my own island and from Mystery Islands, the price they sell for is dis-proportionally lower than the other farming activities throughout my island, such as fish, bugs, and metal.

Answer (score 4):

They're not intended to be farmed, if that's what you mean, as evidenced by their going rate.

They contribute to your island's rating and attract bugs.

Comment: I've heard of some special flowers you can obtain through crossbreeding or golden roses via golden watering can. Are those valuable in any sort of way?

Comment: As a note on the bugs thing, some species of insects only appear around certain colors of flowers.

Comment: @senpai golden roses go for 1000 bells but getting them is too laborious to be a viable farming technique